# How to display all Assets for a Selected Tool

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, html

This is the table where I'm getting the list of my ToolRequests.After Clicking the Assign Button I'll be hiding The table and showing another table.

Here is my table **addUser** where I'm getting all the previous data specific to a particular row. Here how to get a Checkbox having Assets for Given ToolNumber

This is my Html Page.
`

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.button {
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    /* padding: 15px 32px; */
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
   /*  font-size: 16px;
    margin: 4px 2px; */
    cursor: pointer;
}
.button2 {background-color: #008CBA;} /* Blue */
.button3 {background-color: #f44336;} /* Red */ 
</style>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController7">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="card">


        <div class="header">
            <h4 class="title">UnassignedTool Requests List</h4>
            <p class="category">Details of Requests for Tools</p>
        </div>
            <div class="content table-responsive table-full-width">
                <table class="table table-striped" ng-show="table">
                     <thead>

                        <th>Order Number</th>
                        <th>Customer Request Number</th>
                        <th>Field Engineer Name</th>
                        <th>Tool Number</th>
                        <th>Tool Name</th>
                        <th>Tool Quantity</th>
                        <th>Details</th>
                        <th>Action1</th>
                        <th>Action2</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="request in Unassignedrequests">

                            <td>{{request.orderNumber}}</td>
                            <td>{{request.customerRequestNo}}</td>
                            <td>{{request.user.userName}}</td>
                            <td>{{request.tool.toolNumber}}</td>
                            <td>{{request.tool.toolName}}</td>
                            <td>{{request.quantity}}</td>
                            <td>{{request.details}}</td>
                            <td><button class="btn btn-info btn-fill btn-wd" ng-click="edit(request)" >Assign</button> </td>
                            <td><button class="btn btn-info btn-fill btn-wd" ng-click="deleteUser(user.customer_id)" >Reject</button></td>

                        </tr>
                    </tbody> 
                    </table>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
    <pre>
    <form ng-show="addUser">
    <label>   ORDER NUMBER   </label> <input type="text"  ng-model="request.orderNumber"> <br>
     <label>  CUSTOMER REQUEST NUMBER</label> <input type="text" ng-model="request.customerRequestNo"> <br>
     <label>  FIELD ENGINEER NAME</label>     <input type="text"  ng-model="request.user.userName"> <br>
     <label>  TOOL NUMBER</label>             <input type="text"  ng-model="request.tool.toolNumber"> <br>
     <label>  TOOL NAME</label>               <input type="text"  ng-model="request.tool.toolName"> <br>
    <label>   QUANTITY</label>                <input type="text" ng-model="request.quantity"><br>
    <label>   DETAILS</label>                 <input type="text"  ng-model="request.details"> <br>
    <label>   REQUIRED FROM DATE</label>      <input type="date" id="myDate">
    <!-- <button ng-click="insertUser(user)" ng-show="insert">insert</button> -->
    <button ng-click="updateUser(request)" ng-show="edit" > &#9998;submit</button>
    </form>
    </pre>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

`

**This is My Angular Controller**

```
myApp.controller("myController7", function($scope, $http, $state,UnassignedRequests) {
$scope.table=true;
$scope.addUser=false;

UnassignedRequests.getAllUnassignedRequests().then(function(response) {
    if (response != undefined) {
        $scope.Unassignedrequests = response.data;
    }
});
 $scope.edit=function(request){
     $scope.table=false;
     $scope.addUser=true;
     $scope.update=true;
     $scope.insert=false;
     $scope.request=request;
 } ; });
```

**This is My Angular Service**

```
myApp.factory('UnassignedRequests',function($http) {
return {
    getAllUnassignedRequests : function() {
        return $http
        .get('/Tool_Management/WareHouseManager/getAllUnassignedRequests',
                {
                    'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
                }).then(function(response) {
                    return response;
                });
    }

}});
```

**How to get the Assets for Selected ToolNumber**

Comment: I don't `ng-app` & `ng-controller` directive on your page. then how would you expect it to work??

Comment: I have added the ng-app and ng-controller. Actually, this is not the index page, I added ng-app and ng-controller on Index.html